# Water supply line not capped?

Tags: cpvc

Recently while replacing a water shutoff valve in an upstairs vanity, I accidentally broke the CPVC pipe in the wall behind the shutoff valve. After cutting open the drywall to effect the repair, I discovered that the vertical supply line extended approximately 6 inches past the shutoff valve t junction and ended but was not capped. I understand why the extension in the pipe exist to prevent water bump. However I would’ve expected to find it capped at the end. No signs of any water damage and the home is approximately 30 years old. I replaced the cpvc with an exact replica of what I found installed but it’s not sitting easy with me. Is this code in Florida? How many other supply lines terminate in an uncapped pipe I wonder? Obviously I’m not an expert but is there a chance the water could ever "creep" up the pipe and start gushing in the wall. The end of the line is about 6" above the water shutoff but several inched below the faucet in the bathroom sink? Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something not right, an open pipe on the supply line will have water flowing out of it.  It might have an internal cap or blocked/close some other way.

Comment: With my amateur knowledge of plumbing I would expect the same thing. I was shocked when I pulled the uncapped pipe out of the wall but alas, no signs it’s ever overflown.

Comment: Imagine if you put something(wire/coat hanger) down it, it will be blocked.  It is the reason for shutoff valves, so water does not flow out of open ended pipes.

Comment: Yeah I’m confused. I could explain that the water routes through the stop and out the faucet when called for. But, when you turn the faucet off, why doesn’t the water pressure push water out the top of the pipe? I’m guessing science somehow I just don’t know why? It is an upstairs vanity. Maybe not enough water pressure that high up?

Comment: Yeah, this does not add up. If you have the parts you removed, examine for an internal plug. If you installed an open pipe, expect a gusher. For water to come out of the faucet at all, much less at any reasonable flow, pressure in the wall has to be considerably higher than an open pipe below the level of the faucet would support.

Comment: This is interesting. CAN WE HAVE A PICTURE

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UNP7OYU

The vertical pipe goes up about 6 inches and is not capped. I ran water through it as I took this picture and as you see, not a gusher. Somehow the pressure doesn’t push past the stop valve but when needed, plenty of pressure through the faucet.

Comment: I actually did this over a year ago. Although I was curious, I only just now decided to ask a community about it. Unfortunately, I no longer have the original broken pipe to compare.

Comment: Let me admit that because it was so long ago I may be misremembering how long the vertices pipe goes. Maybe it’s 10" but no matter how long, it isn’t capped. I thought maybe you all would point out some kind of pressure vs. vertical rise science to me and put my mind at ease. I’m now wondering why this wouldn’t have been caught in 1992 when the house was built? How many more are like this?

Comment: And why don’t I have water damage? 

Comment: That pipe has/had to be capped/blocked someway or go to something else.  There is no way on earth that if that pipe was open, water would not flow out of it.  The only way was if the pipe was ~100 feet high or more.  Imagine it is capped in a way you did not recognize as a cap.